# bit manipulation in CircuitPython

Tags: python, micropython, adafruit-circuitpython

I've to perform bit-level operations using CircuitPython, like extracting and manipulating 3 bits from a bytes() object.

In normal Python I use the Bitarray library.
Is there an equivalent for CircuitPython?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even with regular Python it's typical to use the bitwise `&` and `|` operators and the bitwise shift operators for setting/selecting various bits. E.g., to test the 6th bit of an integer value:

```
if myValue & 0b100000:
  print('bit 6 was set')
else:
  print('bit 6 was not set')
```

To set bits 4-6:

```
myValue |= 0b111000
```

To extract bits 4-6:

```
extract = (myValue & 0b111000) >> 3
```

Etc.

Comment: Thank you! I am not used to bit operation, your approach is illuminating!

Comment: [This article](https://realpython.com/python-bitwise-operators/) looks like a pretty comprehensive overview of the topic.